# EF Core cant translate simple where linq expression

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

we recently upgraded to use ef core 2.1.8, and now some of our queries are failing.

Something as simple as a where clause causes ef to evaluate it locally.

I have a language table, with a name column, i wanna select all where name is not null, but neither of these two works:

```
var searchQuery  = from q in context.Language
                          where (q.Name != null) select q;

var searchQuery = context.Language.Where(x => x.Name != null);
```

Both are being evaluated locally. Name is a simple string / nvarchar column.

Edit:

Language is a partial class that looks like this:

```
public partial class Language
{
    public Language()
    {
        Segmentation = new HashSet<Segmentation>();
        SystemTranslation = new HashSet<SystemTranslation>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Culture { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Segmentation> Segmentation { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SystemTranslation> SystemTranslation { get; set; }
}

public partial class Language : IIdentifiable<int>, ISearchable
{
    public string Name => CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Culture).DisplayName;
}
```

With the following configuration:

```
void IEntityTypeConfiguration<EF.Entity.Core.Language>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EF.Entity.Core.Language> builder)
    {
        builder.HasIndex(e => e.Culture)
              .HasName("IX_Culture")
              .IsUnique();
    }
```

Comment: How do you know they are being evaluated locally? SQL Profiler?

Comment: Often means that `Name` is not in the database or marked as `[NotMapped]`. If that's not the case, I would use `.ToList()` or at least something to get a result instead of checking it with the debug tool.

Comment: What does `Language` look like? And its EF-configuration?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto EF Core now spits out the `[Warning]` message to the log sink whenever any part of the `IQueryable` will be evaluated locally and cannot be transformed into query. Just an FYI.

Comment: @Jeremy F, good catch, the name is not actually in the database.

Comment: @JonasOlesen `Name` is a calculated property. The condition should be `where q.Culture!= null`

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I've seen that message, doesn't mean the OP was reading that though. We shouldn't assume stuff like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out i was trying to query on a calculated property, which of course means that ef was unable to use it server side, as no column by that name existed.

Comment: maybe a L2E library like this would help - https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq
or this one - https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler